# Facetime for Ubuntu?

Tags: ipod

I like to video chat with my friends, but they have iPods and do not have Skype. I also am not a fan of plugging my iPhone into my computer to charge while I FaceTime. Is there a way I can FaceTime directly from my Ubuntu system, preferably not involving Wine or PlayOnLinux or whatever, or is there an application that is compatible with FaceTime that I can install on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to let you know that AFAIK, Facetime is only available on OSX and iOS.
I am yet to find a third-party client that can connect to that network.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Camfrog

Free live webcam video chat room software for multiple desktop platforms including mobile platforms like iOS and Android.

Make free live audio & video calls world-wide or Join live webcam chat rooms or host your own for free with Blazing fast streaming video and amazing audio quality and a live webcam user photo directory makes it easy to meet new people

[Official Website](http://www.camfrog.com/en/)

### JumpChat

Video chat, file share, and screen share without the need for accounts.

[Official Website](http://jumpch.at/)

### Trillian

Trillian is an instant messaging app that works on phones, tablets, and desktops while keeping your chats neatly synchronized between all of them! We think conversation should be easily shared between all of your devices, not trapped as text messages on your phone.

[Official Website](http://trillian.im/)

[Source](https://alternativeto.net/software/facetime/?platform=linux)

Comment: I need something that can connect to the FaceTime network

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Tox

https://tox.chat/download.html

is has client for iOS (Antidote)

*Instant messaging*
Chat instantly across the globe with Tox's secure messages.

*Voice*

Keep in touch with friends and family using Tox's completely free and encrypted voice calls.

*Video*

Catch up face to face, over Tox's secure video calls.

*Screen sharing*

Share your desktop with your friends with Tox's screen sharing.

*File sharing*

Trade files, with no artificial limits or caps.

*Groups*

Chat, call, and share video and files with the whole gang in Tox's group chats.

Comment: iOS needs Version 8+, able to use Ubuntu 16.04 with qTox, communicating with iPad using Antidote for Tox.  Internet bandwith sensitive but works.  qTox on Win 7 also works.